# TextBox с подсказкой

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Где то недавно видел и потерял где... Такая штука в общем: TextBox у которого когда он пустой отображается внутри подсказка (такая затененная) для чего он нужен, чтобы не делать рядом отдельный TextBlock для подсказки. И пропадает (подсказка) стоит только ему только получить фокус. Помогите кодом пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2):

Такой контрол есть в пакете MahApps.

Пример кода:

```
<TextBox Controls:TextBoxHelper.Watermark="This is a textbox" />
```

Пример на картинке:

[image: Пример контрола]

[Источник](http://mahapps.com/controls/textbox.html)

[Скачать](http://mahapps.com/)

Comment: это что то не встроенное? Не хочется тащить целую либу ради TextBox-а.

Comment: вот здесь нарыл что то типа того, все встроенными средствами: http://rikker.ru/textbox-s-opisaniem-i-kartinkoj-v-wpf

Comment: @DarkByte Встроенного Watermark - я не находил. Работаю только с этим. Смотрится достаточно красиво и есть хоть какие-то стили

Comment: @DarkByte то что нашли - нагружает проект не меньше, чем новая либа. тем более, что красиво и практично врятли получится сделать, а так уже все готово. только скачать

Comment: можно еще попробовать и так http://stackoverflow.com/questions/833943/watermark-hint-text-placeholder-textbox-in-wpf

Comment: вы уверены что это работает? Я скачал протестить, а чего то оно никакой подсказки не выводит...

Comment: @DarkByte mahapps - работает 100%. Просто необходимо внимательно читать как его правильно настроить. Инструкция есть на главной странице сайта. Пользуюсь таким уже очень давно. За все остальное - не ручаюсь, это выдача гугла

Comment: ну не знаю, факт то что я поставил через нугет ее, подключил в xaml, устанавливаю Watermark, ошибок никаких, но и подсказки нет...

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38572/discussion-between-yurii-manziuk-and-dark-byte).

Answer (score 0):

Ну, по-всякому. Например, положить сверху невидимый для hit test'а textblock и управлять видимостью через триггеры:

```
<Grid VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <TextBox Name="tb" Width="100"/>
    <TextBlock Foreground="LightGray"
               Text="Введите текст..."
               IsHitTestVisible="False"
               MaxWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=tb}">
        <TextBlock.Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding IsKeyboardFocused, ElementName=tb}"
                                       Value="False"/>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding Text, ElementName=tb}"
                                       Value="{x:Static sys:String.Empty}"
                                       xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBlock.Style>
    </TextBlock>
</Grid>
```